# loading jQuery/JavaScript in functions.php (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to load a google maps function into the functions.php file of my wordpress theme.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&extension=.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" >
< !-- updatepage(); //-->< /script >

< /script >
```

I've been told by the creator of the theme to call it out using the `wp_enqueue_script()` function in this .php file.

My problem is that when I try to call it out, the `<` are causing problems...**apparently I don't know how to call it out in the right format**....how can I insert this correctly so that my fullscreen google maps works correctly?

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&extension=.js', array('jquery'));`

Comment: When you're unsure of how something works, read the documentation. Wordpress has an entire codex devoted to it, with examples of how just about every function works.

Comment: awesome. i'll try that and see if it works. danke!

Comment: @user3537256 Show us your current php code.

Comment: adeneo: i tried using that the above wp coding.....don't know what I'm doing wrong, or what in my original question I can take out...updatepage, type=text.....i keep getting an error message

Comment: I would suggest you try the solution I posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a .js file for the jQuery code  you want to run.

For the purposes of this example i'm going to name this file `customjquery.js`. You can name it whatever you want, but be sure to edit the code below to reflect the new filename if you do.

**1]** Create a `customjquery.js` file:

```
(function($) {
  updatepage();
})(jQuery);
```

**2]** Then you need to place that customjquery.js file into the `/js/` directory of your theme.

**3]** Add this code to your themes `functions.php` file:

```
function my_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('google-maps-api', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&extension=.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('my-custom-jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/customjquery.js', array('jquery'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_scripts');
```

If you would like to place the `customjquery.js` file somewhere else in your theme folder, just update the path in the code above to reflect the file's new location.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to include it on your web page, then you may just echo it using proper add_action(). But, if you want to run it with your functions.php then I recommend converting the code to php or wp_enqueue_script().